# Replace characters from string using scala

Tags: java, scala

How to replace characters from a given string.

I wrote the following code, but here it iterates over the chars.

```
val chars = "\\`*{}[]()<>#+:~'%^&@?;,.\"!$=|"
var newString = inputString 
chars.map { c =>
  if (inputString.contains(c)){
    newString = newString.replace(c, '_')
  }
}
```

I'm looking at code similar to below.  Unfortunately, it is throwing an error. Can someone help me to figure out the error?

```
scala> "hello:world".replaceAll("\\`*{}[]()>#+:~'%^&@<?;,\"!$=|.", "_")
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 2
\`*{}[]()>#+:~'%^&@<?;,"!$=|.
^
```

It turns out that the first argument needs to be a regular expression for the argument, and not a list of characters, but I still get an error:

```
scala> "hello:world".replaceAll("[`*{}[]()>#+:~'%^&@<?;,\"!$=|.]", "_")
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 29
[`*{}[]()>#+:~'%^&@<?;,"!$=|.]
                             ^
```

Comment: You have to escape the regex metacharacters correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You did not escape all of the characters in the regex that need escaping.
This works:

```
"hello:world".replaceAll("[\\`\\*{}\\[\\]()>#\\+:\\~'%\\^&@<\\?;,\"!\\$=\\|\\.]", "_")
```

but I'm guessing that what you really want is:

```
"hello:world".replaceAll("\\W", "_")
```

Comment: To avoid having to Java-escape the Regex-escape slash, you can also use triple double quotes. Besides, you forgot the slash, and the fact that some special characters need not be escaped in `[]` clause in regex: `"""[\\`*{}\[]()>#+:~'%^&@<?;,"!$=|.]"""`.

Comment: Yeah, the answer is correct.  It just suffers from "backslash paranoia".

Answer (score 2):

If you escape the square braces with backslashes, the regular expression pattern should compile:

```
scala> "hello:world".replaceAll("[`*{}\\[\\]()>#+:~'%^&@<?;,\"!$=|.]", "_")
res0: String = hello_world
```

You could probably just use the character classes to write it more succinctly:

```
scala> "hello:world".replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "_")
res1: String = hello_world
```